# Django: How to add a user as a foriegn key in a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django. I want to add user as a foreign key in the manager model and i have no idea how can i do this.

this is my manager model

```
class manager(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
designation = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
```

I have to add user as a foreign key in the manager.

Comment: what part of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships) isn't clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class manager(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

if you are not using any custom User model you can do it like this

Comment: AUTH_USER_MODEL maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='managers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
```

This will require a user instance compulsory but if you want to make it optional

```
user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        blank=True, # allow Blank
        null=True,  # allow Null
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, # prevent ForiegnKey Contraint error
)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The `related_name` attribute specifies the name of the reverse relation from the `User` model back to your model.

If you don't specify a related_name, Django automatically creates one using the name of your model with the `suffix _set`, for instance `User.manager_set.all()`.

If you do specify, e.g. `related_name=managers` on the `User` model, `User.managers_set` will still work, but the `User.managers.` syntax is obviously a bit cleaner and less clunky.

The [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) has more details.